# Google Analytics Stopped Tracking My Site After I Reinstalled Google Analyticator Plugin

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

Last week I was looking for a bug that was causing my site to crash every time I updated the page and I thought that by deleting my plugins, which weren't many, would help resolve this issue. Deleting the plugins didn't help, but I did figure out that other problem. So, last week I reinstalled the plugin Google Analyticator and the process when through normally, however I checked today google analytics is reporting that no one is on my site. I was on the site at least 5 times a day, so it should report something.

I checked the page view and the account number for google analytics is correct and the tracking code is in the header. How else should I go about finding where this problem?

Comment: Can you give us a link to your site, otherwise we can`t see if google analyticator is loading the analytics script correctly

Comment: I would contact the creators of the plugin, I don't think this is something you can get help with on stack